# Sugessions on defining the Technical Stack for my Hadoop infra structe

Tags: hadoop, hive, nosql

I am planning to build a new system in Hadoop, that brings data from External Environment and then do some transformations and builds up a end product.

The external data (if we can assume it is from either oracle/mysql/postgre-sql data base, there can be n-data bases schema) that comes to hadoop system should be always real time (new data should get inserted and updated data should get updated), may be atleast an hour delay at max (we can poll/push hourly basis).

We can also assume the data that exists in my data base schema is with n-tables, I may need m-tables only out of n-tables that exists in source. And each table data of size in GB/TB. So I can't go with full table replace. I should always go incremental(updates/inserts) push/pull into hadoop system.

Hive may support, by dividing my data into date wise partitions, and can query faster, but doesn't not support updates so I have to go for full table replace always, which does not scalable.

My end goal is "Real time data into hadoop system, read query performace, update performance".

Your Technical suggestions for my use case is very useful.

Comment: If you are using Hive 0.14 version or newer then it provide update functionality.

Comment: I have done some ground work before replying to this post, yes I do agree with you, that hive 14 supports updates, but it has come very recently (in the beginning of 2015) and not sure how the support is available for hive 14. I have also made some progress on NoSQL systems, if we denormalize the tables then we can use NoSQL system very effectively. We can have some indexes created in "SOLAR/Lucin", then it is very easy to query the data and update the data. But the question I rasied to my self is how effectively we can create a ROWKeyID that suites for all the tables to de-normalize the data.